# How to make PeoplePicker a required field?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, people-picker, validation

I have a form with a couple PeoplePickers and I'd like to require the user to make a selection for the people picker, but unlike a text box field, I can't figure out how to require a peoplepicker.  Appreciate any help/suggestions...

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="peoplePickerUser" class="required">Requestor</label>
        <div id="peoplePickerUser"></div>
    </div>
</div>

function resolvePeoplePicker() {
    var peoplePickerUser= this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerUser_TopSpan;
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerUser_TopSpan.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function (peoplePickerId, selectedUsersInfo) {
        ///all kinds of code for finding the id's from the people picker
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the people picker field is filled or not on click of your form Submit like below:

```
var peoplePickerElement = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerUser_TopSpan;

var usersList = peoplePickerElement.GetAllUserInfo();

if(usersList.length) {
    console.log("Users added");
}
else {
    alert("This field is required!");
    return;
}
```

If there are no users then you can show some message to add the users in people picker field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code.

Note:  Here through the line `$("[title='Requester']").attr("id")`, we are getting th ID of the people picker control whose title is `Requester`.

So You can Replace `Requester` with the title of your people picker control. And It will work ..

```
if(SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[$("[title='Requester']").attr("id")].GetAllUserInfo().length == 0){
    // people picker is empty
}else{
    // people picker is NOT empty
}
```